# filters for table columns is not working in vuejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have done below code is not working for filter in table. I have received the data from `API`, when I try to enter something in search box, nothing is showing in table except header. Please help me what wrong I am doing here.

Below code is in `app.vue` file.
This is the table:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Quotes List</h1>
    <button class="button" v-on:click="getquotes()">Get Quotes</button>
    <br> <input v-model="filterInput">
    <br>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead style="background-color:#22376f;color:#ffff;margin-top:20px">
        <th>QuoteNo</th>
      <th>CustomerName</th>
      <th>Revision</th>
      <th>QuoteAmount</th>
      <th>CustContact</th>
       <th>QuoteType</th>
       <th>Status</th>
       <th>ModifiedOn</th>
       <th>CreatedBy</th>
       <th>Owner</th>
       <th>ExpDate</th>
       <th>PriceList</th>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr  v-for="quote in filteredList()"  v-bind:key="quote.QuoteNo">
        <td>{{ quote.QuoteNo }}</td>
        <td>{{ quote.CustomerName }}</td>
        <td>{{ quote.Revision }}</td>
        <td>{{ quote.QuoteAmount }}</td>
        <td>{{ quote.CustContact }}</td>
        <td>{{ quote.QuoteType }}</td>
        <td>{{ quote.Status }}</td>
        <td>{{ quote.ModifiedOn }}</td>
        <td>{{ quote.CreatedBy }}</td>
        <td>{{ quote.Owner }}</td>
        <td>{{ quote.ExpDate }}</td>
        <td>{{ quote.PriceList }}</td>
      </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</template>
```

This is the script:

```
<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      // note: changing this line won't causes changes
      // with hot-reload because the reloaded component
      // preserves its current state and we are modifying
      // its initial state.
      msg: 'Welcome!',
      api: '',
      users: [],
      quotes:[],
      error: {},
      filterInput:''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getquotes: function() {

      this.$http.get({
        url: '/quotes'
      }).then((response) => {
        this.quotes = response.data.result['rows']
        console.log(this.quotes)
      }, (response) => {
        this.error = response.data
      })
    },

  },
  computed: {
  filteredList() {
    const value= this.filterInput.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.filterInput.slice(1);
    return this.quotes.filter(function(quote){
      return  
        quote.QuoteNo.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
       quote.CustomerName.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
         quote.Revision.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
         quote.QuoteAmount.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
         quote.CustContact.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
         quote.QuoteType.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
         quote.Status.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
         quote.ModifiedOn.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
         quote.CreatedBy.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
         quote.Owner.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
         quote.ExpDate.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
         quote.PriceList.indexOf(value) > -1 
    });
  }
}
}
</script>

<style>
body {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No error, when i try to show list in console, it is just simply showing [object,object].......

Comment: Chrome usually shows Vue errors where other browsers like Firefox sometimes don't. I'm pretty sure you don't need the parentheses, `quote in filteredList()` should be `quote in filteredList`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I removed parentheses now this time I am not getting any records in table on button click. (I got records from api in console). Can you please suggest me whats wrong there

Comment: Are there any records that match the filter you've entered?

Comment: I am trying same data as in table

Comment: Even I tried this code <tr  v-for="quote in filterBy(quotes,filterInput)" > where filterBy is funtion in methods with two parameters having same code as filteredList

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185351/discussion-between-nakul-and-jaybird).

Comment: It's the same issue with the parentheses. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer:

I've created [a working fiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/xgs2ra9p/). There are multiple fixes:

- Removed parentheses in template in `v-for` and on input-event.
- Added parentheses around statement in `filteredList()` method.

---

Bear in mind that [`.indexOf()` is case-sensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: If any of his data is not a string, such as a number, indexOf will not work. He'll have to convert to strings first.

Comment: I appreciate the perfect answer for me, but there is still problem, it is not filtering. CreatedBy: "Sales One Manager"
CustContact: "Zuck Erik"
CustomerName: "Cristiano Ronaldo"
ExpDate: "2018-12-28T18:30:00.000Z"
ModifiedOn: "2018-11-28T18:30:00.000Z"
Owner: "SalesOne Manager"
PriceList: "PLNonRenew"
QuoteAmount: "$0.00"
QuoteNo: "QTE-201811290510030"
QuoteType: "Sales"
Revision: "0"
Status: "Draft"

Comment: I've created an update fiddle with the data here: works as intended. What are you typing into the field? https://jsfiddle.net/xgs2ra9p/1/

Comment: If I give quote.QuoteNo.indexOf(value) > -1  it is working, and if I give all condition it is not working

Comment: Can you suggest me In my case why only first condition is returning(filter) data, and other conditions not even checking? I have done same code as yours.

Comment: The problem is solved, I have enclosed each individual condition in () . I don't know how its affects but code is working fine. Thanks for your great help. Appreciate!